# ORA-00904 invalid identifier in command prompt

Tags: sql

I don't know why this is wrong  as it is surprisingly showing me this error please help to fix it.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
  2  ID NUMBER(2),
  3  NAME VARCHAR2(30),
  4  AGE NUMBER(3),
  5  ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
  6  SALARY FLOAT(4),
  7  );
)
*
```

> ERROR at line 7:
>   ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: Most SQL instances won't let you put a trailing comma in a `CREATE TABLE` statement; instead of `SALARY FLOAT(4),`, line 7 should be `SALARY FLOAT(4)`

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma after the column salary

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
  2  ID NUMBER(2),
  3  NAME VARCHAR2(30),
  4  AGE NUMBER(3),
  5  ADDRESS VARCHAR2(50),
  6  SALARY FLOAT(4)
  7  );
```

Comment: Salary is a _column_, not a field.

Answer (score -1):

If You have not create next line after 6th line I mean the 7th line then it will not be error the query okay now see in the following
Create table customer (
2. ID number (2),
3.Name varchar2(30),
4.Age number(3),
5. Address  varchar2 (50),
6. salary float(4));
 Then click enter 
Table created